# Cannot create Output directory error: 7zip

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I am using 7zip to extract my zip file using powershell with the following code:

```
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"  
sz x -o:$destinationUnzipPath $zipfilePath -r ;
```

and I get the following error:

> ERROR: Can not create output directory: :D:\Temp\4.7-4.8\ System
>   ERROR: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is
>   incorrect.

Even If i create the directory manually, I still get the same error.

and If i do not provide any output directory, following is the Output

> 7-Zip [64] 16.04 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-10-04
>
> Scanning the drive for archives: 1 file, 140483197 bytes (134 MiB)
>
> Extracting archive: D:\Temp\4.7-4.8.zip
>   -- Path = D:\Temp\4.7-4.8.zip Type = zip Physical Size = 140483197
>
> Everything is Ok
>
> Folders: 71 Files: 3448 Size:       1709276577 Compressed: 140483197

But I cant find the unzipped files in the zip directory or anywhere else.

Comment: remove the colon from the cmd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a powershell issue but an issue in your command line parameters passed to 7-zip. You have added a colon to the `-o` parameter where it's not needed.

changing this

```
sz x -o:$destinationUnzipPath $zipfilePath -r ;
```

to this should work

```
sz x -o$destinationUnzipPath $zipfilePath -r ;
```

Comment: what is the parameter to skip unzipping if the file already exists?

Comment: You can use `Test-Path $destinationUnzipPath ` to verify if the folder already exists and skip the unzip command.